# How do I select a field/column from the output of `ls -l`?

Tags: command-line, bash

My goal is deceptively simple (at least to me). I wish to take the output of `ls -l` or `ls -lh` and select just one field.

I am looking for this to be as bulletproof as possible, by which I mean, assume that filenames can have a variable number of spaces, not everything in the field has the same length, etc.

Bonus points for having a script that will take the name of the the field (or even just a field number), and then return the contents of the field.

I want to turn

[image]

into:

[image]

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try `ls -l | awk '{print $7}'`.

[`awk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/awk.1posix.html) selects columns so it's perfect for this task.

Comment: As explained by @ormaaj: Do not rely on pieces of information being available in specific places with `ls`. The `find` command is tremendously helpful.

Comment: @PaddyLandau How do I use the find command to print a file size in megabytes like I can with `ls -l --block-size=M`?

Comment: @Benjamin — The `ls` command is not POSIX standard, so a script that depends on `ls` could break on different systems or even over time. See the answer by @ormaaj on this page for more details. One way to do what you ask is with a Bash loop. Here is an example. `for FILENAME in *; do FILESIZE=$(( $( stat --format=%s "${FILENAME}" ) / 1024 )); echo "${FILENAME}" ${FILESIZE}; done`. Of course, instead of `echo`, you'd use your processing.

Comment: @PaddyLandau I just ended up piping the output of the find command to `... | xargs -d '\n' du -m` which works just as well.

Comment: @Benjamin You might want to look at the `-exec` option of `find`.

Comment: This is lowely! One question, how to keep color of ls command?

Answer (score 25):

[Never parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use GNU `find`. Or if portability isn't important, `stat(1)`.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%Td\n'
```

For reading data other than lists of filenames line-by-line and splitting into fields, see: [BashFAQ/001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

There are no methods to reliably read a newline-delimited list of filenames that make sense under most circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

You may fetch the specific column in shell like:

```
ls -al | while read perm bsize user group size month day time file; do echo $day; done
```

or `awk` as shown in [@Corey answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/161803/78223), `cut -c44-45` would also work  after adjustment (since `ls` has fixed columns) , or whatever else, however the main problem is that it won't be reliable and bulletproof (e.g. on Unix it may be `$6`, not `$7`, and it changes depending on arguments) making it not machine-friendly therefore [it is not recommended to parse `ls` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/21471) at all.

The best is to use different available commands such as `find` or `stat`, which can provide relevant options to format the output as you need. For example:

```
$ stat -c "%x %n" *
2016-04-10 04:53:07.000000000 +0100 001.txt
2016-04-10 05:08:42.000000000 +0100 7c1c.txt
```

To return column of only days of modifications, try this example:

```
stat -c "%x" * | while read ymd; do date --date="$ymd" "+%d"; done
```

It's worth to note that GNU `stat` could have different options to BSD `stat`, so it still won't be bulletproof across different operating systems.

Comment: +1 for mention that ls should not be parsed as well as for use of `stat` . `date` however is setup incorrectly. You should add `--date=$ymd` , since `date` by itself will print the current day, but the purpose here is to convert date format of the file

Comment: The `ls -la | cut -c32-33` command in total honesty is just completely unreliable, not only because of the possible pitfalls with the filenames, but simply because it depends on the usernames' length and on the files' size. The `stat -c "%x" *.*` command looks ok, but by using `*.*` you're restricing it only to filenames containing a dot. I guess the intention was to catch also hidden files; in that case you should enable globbing for dotfiles beforehand and use `*` instead of `*.*`: `shopt -s dotglob; stat -c "%x" * | [...]`.

Comment: Ah and what Serg said also, you should add `--date="$ymd"` to the `date` command, otherwise it will print the current day of the month.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've addressed the issues and provided a better initial example.

Answer (score 0):

I need to catalog my installed applications prior to backing up and upgrading and encountered this issue trying to figure out how to trim `ls` output, but the `awk` applications suggested in other Ask Ubuntu questions didn't work at all.

What worked for me were suggestions to use `cut`: I redirected test ls output to a text file and used a "ruler" in Sumblime Text to find the character column numbers

```
total 2060
         1         2         3         4         5
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root      291 2023-04-12 13:53 apport-gtk.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root      277 2023-04-12 13:53 apport-kde-mime.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     3417 2018-04-14 03:38 assistant-qt5.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     1066 2022-03-07 19:03 atom.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     2683 2018-05-01 04:10 audio-recorder.desktop
...
```

and then filtered with cut -c30-, where the trailing hyphen extends rendering to the end of (variable length) lines.

```
$ dir -l --time-style=long-iso /usr/share/applications | cut -c30-

  291 2023-04-12 13:53 apport-gtk.desktop
  277 2023-04-12 13:53 apport-kde-mime.desktop
 3417 2018-04-14 03:38 assistant-qt5.desktop
 1066 2022-03-07 19:03 atom.desktop
 2683 2018-05-01 04:10 audio-recorder.desktop
...
```

This "ruler check" is needed since `ls`'s field alignment is relative after the first access permissions field. For the specific issue here (isolating the day of month) we can identify columns 38 and 39 as our targets.

```
$ ls -l >> cutcheck.txt
$ cat cutcheck.txt
         1         2         3         4         5
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
total 480
-rwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev    112 Mar 12 17:36 cutcheck.txt
-rwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev    112 Mar 12 17:34 cutruler.txt
drwxrwx--- 3 root plugdev  32768 Mar 10 17:53 KDEAppLaucherConfig
-rwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev 195385 Mar  2 18:02 KDEAppLaucherMenuEditorHandbk.pdf
-rwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev   2202 Mar 11 18:30 KDEAppLauncherFiles.txt
-rwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev  40346 Mar  5 21:10 KDEApps.ods
-rwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev  90993 Mar  5 20:12 KDEMenuAppsDesktopFiles.html
$ ls -l | cut -c38-39

12
12
10
 2
11
 5
 5
```

Once you know the "ballpark" character column values for your particular file system, you can issue succesive `cut` commands to isolate what you need to extract.

The `stat` command allows specifying particular `ls`/`dir` output fields, but the neat `ls` column alignment is lost because of the variable field lengths. The application of `awk` given in @Corey Whitaker's answer did work, but with the same loss of column alignment.

I think `stat` is the better choice if the intention is direct import into a spreadsheet catalog because the field codes can be separated with commas for redirection to a CSV file.