# How to separate fields with space or tab in awk

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

While playing with `awk` I came to execute:

```
ls -la >> a.txt ; awk {'print $5  $1'} a.txt ;
```

This is giving output like:

```
53277-rw-------
52347-rw-------
```

How can I get a space between these two friends of output?

Comment: As an advice, you should not parse the output of `ls`. This will bite you in the back sooner or later.

Comment: In awk, to concatenate two strings, you just place them side-by-side -- `print $5 $1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select a field/column from the output of \`ls -l\`?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161802/how-do-i-select-a-field-column-from-the-output-of-ls-l)

Comment: @kenorb and close voters, the linked duplicate is not a duplicate at all. They know already how to print fields by premise (`awk {'print $5  $1'} a.txt`). They're asking how to put a space in between field #1 and field #5.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Just change the line to

```
ls -la >> a.txt ; awk {'print $5 "        " $1'} a.txt ;
```

this should print the output with spaces.

Hope this helps.

Edit:

As suggested by [McNisse](https://askubuntu.com/users/114134/mcnisse) you can use printf, which would provide you good output format

```
ls -la >> a.txt ; awk {'printf ("%5s\t%s\n", $5, $1)'} a.txt ;
```

Comment: The `printf` function provides better control, specially if you want to format numbers. `printf("%s\t%s\n", $5, $1)`

Comment: Is there a typo in above answer? what does `5s` mean in `awk {'printf ("%5s\t%s\n", $5, $1)'}`

Comment: @Vishal - if you insert a number after the % sign, then you specify a field width, in this case 5. The output will be right aligned. If you enter a negative number, the output will be aligned on the left.

Answer (score 101):

Another awk-specific technique, use the "output field separator"

```
ls -la | awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $5, $1}'
```

The comma is crucial here.

Comment: this works but cause `$1` to go to newline

Comment: @loretoparisi, no it doesn't. There are likely to be `\r` characters at your end-of line.

Comment: +1, This is a clean way to do it. Please note that doesn't work with `print $0` to print all fields with the `OFS` separator, so for such a need we can use `column`: `... | column -s ' ' -t`

Answer (score 26):

A simple way to get tabs is:

```
awk {'print $5"\t"$1'}
```

Comment: Thanks I hate it. But slightly less than the other options.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old thread, but I'm just learning and found these posts helpful. My best solution was to use gawk to insert spaces between the variables for you.

```
ls -la | gawk '{print $1, $9}'
```

Comment: -1: Nothing new. `gawk`, `mawk`, or any other `awk`, they all insert spaces if you use the comma, which is what [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/232037/158442) says.

Comment: Should be `ls -la | awk '{print $1, $9}'`. As muru said `gawk` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 6):

To place the space between the arguments, just add `" "`, e.g. `awk {'print $5"  "$1'}`.

However it is **not** recommended to [parse output of `ls` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/21471), since it's not reliable and output is for humans, not scripts. Therefore use alternative commands such as `find` or `stat`.

Here is example using GNU `stat`:

```
$ stat -t *
001.txt 23 8 81a4 501 20 1000004 242236402 1 0 0 1460260387 1460260239 1460260239 1460260194 4096
7c1c.txt 21 8 81a4 501 20 1000004 242236595 1 0 0 1460261322 1460260486 1460260486 1460260486 4096
```

which will print you machine-friendly output (in terse form), so you can get exactly what you need. Then use `-c` to use specific format, or use `awk`, `cut` or `read` to get the right columns.

Check `stat --help` for further options. For example to print day of modification, check [this example](https://askubuntu.com/a/755768/78223).

Comment: It appears the OP is trying to parse the output for human reading purposes and not for the purposes of running a script (like `for i in ls; do $i`).