# How to handle multiple parameters from a user's selection in a checklist menu?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, dialog

I'm creating script that runs commands based on information from a checklist dialog:

```
dialog --checklist "Choose what you want to install:" 0 0 0  1 mysql on 2 java on  3 git off 2> tempfile
```

[image: dialog box]

I have the correct data in `tempfile` (`1` `2`), but I don't know how to use this data in future in my script.

Comment: No, that question about **inbox** dialog, but I asked about **chesklist** dialog. **Inbox** returns one parameter, but i want to handle few parameters, which checked in **checkbox**

Comment: but the answer is the same....

Answer (score 3):

You can use `--output-fd 1` to send output to stdout and then capture it as normal.

```
answer=$(dialog --checklist "Choose what you want to install:" 0 0 0  1 mysql on 2 java on  3 git off --output-fd 1)
```

Comment: Ok, answer accept data "1 2". How to split and use them in future?

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816820/use-space-as-a-delimiter-with-cut-command) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231995/how-to-separate-fields-with-space-or-tab-in-awk) ...